# FullCalendar plugin dayClick not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I've been trying to get the dayClick in the FullCalendar plugin to work, but when I click nothing is happening. Can't figure out what it is I'm doing wrong. I click on a day, but no alert message. jsfiddle below. What am I doing wrong.

http://jsbin.com/bicawa/2/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alert` is turned off in JSBin. You shouldn't debug with `alert` because it stops code execution. While JSBin is a great tool for building quick samples, it makes debugging harder.

And as @idoberko2 says: You should put jQuery as first included script.

Here is a working [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qihiheneme/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know this library but you had two non-related issues in your code:

1. The moment script tag was placed before jQuery, my guess it should be placed after.
2. You had four slashes in your moment src (i.e. `src="https:////..."`)
   After fixing these two issues I got the `console.log` to work, but for some reason the `alert()` still wasn't working.